# Define a preferred linebreak to wrap content in a flex box row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to define a preferred break spot in a flex box that has word wrap enabled?

There is a similar question here:

[Linebreak in a column flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64444689/linebreak-in-a-column-flexbox)

And this one:

[How to specify line breaks in a multi-line flexbox layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29732575/441016)

But they are not the same.

I cannot use Grid because it is not supported. It must be flex box.

Basically, I have about 10 items in a Flexbox row. If they can't all fit I want them to break and wrap to a new line at the 8th item. I'd like "break at item 8 if all items can't fit on one line" if that makes sense.

Comment: _"I cannot use Grid because it is not supported"_ - not supported by whom? Even IE11 and IE10 supports CSS `display: grid;`

Comment: @Dai It's not a browser it has limited display features

Comment: Oh? I'm genuinely curious - can you share any details? (This is the first time I've heard of a layout engine that can do flex but not grid...)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this. You need to add `flex-wrap:wrap;` to the parent item and use max-width on the child based on the viewport. When the combined width will reach 100%, the next element will break.

After adding `flex-wrap` you are already wrapping the elements, the width will just expand and hold it to a specific screen resolution.

I hope this is what you need!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  /*EXTRA STYLES*/
  gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.child {
  max-width: 11vw;
  width: 100%;
  /*EXTRA STYLES*/
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fefefe;
  border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'> 1 </div>
  <div class='child'> 2 </div>
  <div class='child'> 3 </div>
  <div class='child'> 4 </div>
  <div class='child'> 5 </div>
  <div class='child'> 6 </div>
  <div class='child'> 7 </div>
  <div class='child'> 8 </div>
  <div class='child'> 9 </div>
  <div class='child'> 10 </div>
  <div class='child'> 1 </div>
  <div class='child'> 2 </div>
  <div class='child'> 3 </div>
  <div class='child'> 4 </div>
  <div class='child'> 5 </div>
  <div class='child'> 6 </div>
  <div class='child'> 7 </div>
  <div class='child'> 8 </div>
  <div class='child'> 9 </div>
  <div class='child'> 10 </div>
</div>
```